# Error in C# Script for Unity, how do I read this CSV file into an array?

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, unity-game-engine

I am trying to work on this Typing Game in Unity for class. One of the requirements is to read the words from a CSV file of random words into an array. I have everything working in the program when I manually create the array of words, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how I am supposed to read a CSV file into an array. None of the solutions I found online do anything at all but create compiler errors. Here is the code for the script I have to generate words.

I've tried using "StreamReader" and can't even figure out how it works, and every other solution I've found on this site. Every one is different and none work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateWords : MonoBehaviour {

    TextAsset words = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("words");
    private static string[] wordList = words.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

    public static string GetRandomWord ()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, wordList.Length);
        string randomWord = wordList[randomIndex];

        return randomWord;
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

> Assets/Scripts/GenerateWords.cs(28,40): error CS0236: A field
>   initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property
>   `GenerateWords.words'

Comment: the issue is that `wordList` is `static`, but it references `words`, which is not. Since a static variable can be used without initialising an instance of the class, the compiler cannot allow it to rely on a non-static variable (which can't exist when the class has not been instantiated), because a situation could arise where someone wants to use `wordList`, but at that time `words` does not exist.

Comment: If you don't understand what `static` does when declared on a property or method, now would be a great time to go and [find out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members). Or maybe you know exactly what it does, but just made a typo and omitted `static` from the declaration of `words`. It's unclear.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add "static" to words, yeah. Although you're right, I also don't fully understand what it means, even after reading what you linked. It all went waaay over my head. But I got it working for the most part. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. If the stuff about `static` went way over your head then I think you need to spend some time studying object-oriented principles, and how you use classes in C# (and other OO languages). It's a key point you'll need to fully grasp before you can really succeed in using the language. P.S. I gave you the official MS documentation, but if you google it you might find tutorials etc which give clearer explanations and worked examples to help you. it's research time...enjoy, and good luck :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `wordList` is marked as `static`, but it then makes use of `words`, which is not static.

Since a `static` variable can be used without initialising an instance of the class, the compiler cannot allow it to rely on a non-static variable, because a non-static variable cannot exist when the class has not been instantiated. This is because a situation could arise where someone wants to use `wordList`, but because it's `static`, is it not in the context of any particular instantiated object of this type. Since `words` can only belong to a specific copy of the class, `wordList` can never access it when it's not in the context of the class.

You can probably find clearer explanations of static properties and methods elsewhere online, but that's my basic take on it.

Anyway the simplest way to resolve your issue is to make all your properties static:

Change

```
TextAsset words = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("words");
```

to

```
static TextAsset words = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("words");
```